# How to externalize application.yml in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Hi Currently my project is using application.yml from src/main/resources by default. I want to use the application.yml file in a different location, so as I can edit the properties whenever I want. Please suggest any idea

Comment: are you looking for a centralized config management server something like spring-cloud ? https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: It is microservice gateway app. It is using spring cloud. But I just want this applicatin.yml file to be accessed externally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot lets you externalize your configuration so that you can work with the same application code in different environments. You can use properties files, YAML files, environment variables, and command-line arguments to externalize configuration. Property values can be injected directly into your beans by using the `@Value` annotation, accessed through Spring’s `Environment` abstraction, or be bound to structured objects through `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Detailed Information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Set `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable example

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dspring.config.location=file:C:/application-external.yml
```

This will allow you to have provide multiple profiles inside of a YML file and let spring do the heavy lifting of evaluating the correct properties:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
someproperty: devproperty
---
spring:
  profiles: test
someproperty: testproperty
```

To use external configuration files in your Maven build : configure the maven surefire plugin like this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
     <argLine>-Dspring.config.location=file:${home}/conf/application-external.yml
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I'm using jhipster microservice gateway. I use mvnw to run the application. i prefe to provide the location in code.I tried passing as argument, it doesnt work.

Comment: @Nila Try with the spring.config.location environment property. Imagine you have an external config file: application-external.yml in the conf/ dir under your home directory, just add it like this: -Dspring.config.location=file:${home}/conf/application-external.yml as a startup parameter of your JVM. If you have multiple files, just seperate them with a comma. Note that you can easily use external properties like this to overwrite properties, not just add them.

Comment: @Nila Updated answer with providing external configuration files with location in your Maven pom.xml

Comment: I tried all, But it is still taking from the war file(target folder). :-(

Comment: @Nila try using relative path like spring.config.location=file:///application-external.yml

Comment: Hi Joe, I used below code in bootstrap.yml. It worked. Thanks.   config:
         location:  file:/C:/projects/Jhipster/application-external.yml

Comment: @Nila Glad that I was able to help you :)